Badge's text color becomes hardly visible after visiting
I noticed this morning that the "Newest Badge" text in the Activity tab in user profile (including other user's Activity tab and both Meta/Main Site) is barely visible.
Looks like its due to the :visited style being applied after I've clicked into it. Seems like this style is excluded for other badges, but not the Newest Badge. Is this a bug?
This seems to happen under all browsers.


Also reported here: Dark Gray/Black is poor choice for colour on visited links

Oh right, thanks! I've tried to search if its reported but didn't find this post.
